# jQuery change() on <select> and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown that triggers an ajax call when its changed:

```
$('.travel-to').change(function(){  
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/inc/rates/rates-viewer.php",
        data: "shtech=y&c_name="+escape($(this).val()),
        success: function(html){
            $(".rates-viewer").html(html);
            $(".rates-viewer tr.numbers td").css({ opacity: 0 }).fadeTo("slow",1);
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is, in Firefox, using the up/down cursor keys to cycle through the dropdown options, doesn't trigger the js `onChange()` event. It's ok in IE.

How can I make Firefox see the up/down cursors as an `onChange`? Can I do an either/or on the event, to make either an `onChange` or a keypress trigger the same thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're actually taking advantage of a bug in IE.  Firefox supports onChange correctly, as it's not supposed to fire until the browser loses focus of the select field.  (I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580281/redirect-automatically-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-select-drop-down-list/580317#580317) yesterday about this very issue, in fact.)  It's actually kind of dangerous to use onChange with a select, especially because there's no way for keyboard only users to skip some options.  (On top of that, the mouse wheel *seems* to spin by multiple answers, but it actually fires onChange for each entry it passes by on IE.)

If you really want the event to fire whenever someone presses up or down, I would hook into the onKeyPress or onKeyDown events to fire whenever the "up" or "down" key is pressed.

Comment: This is happening to me was well. The 'change' event is firing correctly in Safari, Chrome, AND IE.  Seems like its become standard functionality for this event to fire WHEN an element is changed, not after it loses focus; thats what 'focusout' is for. Again this may be only been introduced to modern browsers recently, either way FF should adopt this change.

Comment: I'm solving this problem by simply adding a "Go" button next to the select box, so the user has full control.

Answer (score 8):

better option is use `.on()` to bind function as multiple events

```
$("#member").on("change keyup", function(){
    -----
});
```

Comment: Love it. Sane cross browser behavior

Comment: Amazing! Thank you :)

Comment: Splendid, this need to be the best answer here. Thank you.

Comment: Runs the callback twice when browser fires both `change` and `keyup`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of using the change() event use the blur() event and check to see if the value changed?

FYI, i have not tested this, just an idea that I had. and I am not sure if this is the desired effect because it would trigger on a lost of focus, but I am suggesting it as to keep the effect consistent across different browsers.

```
var currentValue;

$('.travel-to').blur(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (currentValue != val) {
        currentValue = val;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/inc/rates/rates-viewer.php",
            data: "shtech=y&c_name="+escape(currentValue),
            success: function(html){
                $(".rates-viewer").html(html);
                $(".rates-viewer tr.numbers td").css({ opacity: 0 }).fadeTo("slow",1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work well, because you have to click on something else before blur fires (a least in Chrome and FF3.6) - just tried this method

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced some weird behavior in firefox which enables the user to open the select dropdown, navigate with the arrows and then instead of tabbing out or clicking on a side the user can click another element which will result into changing the select value without firing `change` event.

To work around this you can trigger the `change` whenever the `keyup` (please also suggest other events?) event is fired and the select has a different value then the previous.

```
var selectRegistry = {},
    $selects = $('select');

$selects.bind('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    selectRegistry[$this.attr('id')] = $this.val();
});

$selects.bind('keyup scroll select', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val()!=selectRegistry[$this.attr('id')])
    {
        $this.trigger('change');
    }
});
```

You can use `.live()` function if you'll have dinamically created select elements along the runtime of the web page.

Comment: or even better (if you use jQuery >=1.7) use the `.on()` method instead of `.live()`. See http://www.jqapi.com/#p=on

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using jquery [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/