# Insert one HTML file in another dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

There are 2 html files, file-1.htm and file-2.htm. There is another html file, test.htm, with a drop-down having 2 values, "Load Sample-1" and "Load Sample-2".

This is what I am trying:
When "Load Sample-1" is selected from the drop-down, file-1.htm should be loaded as a nested html in test.htm.

Right now I am able to achieve this through javascript by having the content of file-1.htm and file-2.htm inside test.htm. Bt as the drop-down grows bigger, test.htm would become huge. How can this be achieved by having separate html files for each entry in the drop-down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you just use an [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp), and then have the JavaScript dynamically change the source of the iframe?

Here's a bare-bones page demonstrating how to use this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var changePage = function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");  // One of the many ways to select your iframe
    var select = document.getElementById("pageselected");
    var url = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    iframe.src = url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="pageselected">
    <option value="page1.html">Page 1</option>
    <option value="page2.html">Page 2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="changePage()" value="Change Page" />
<iframe id="myiframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

You may be asking yourself "why did he not just use `onchange` for the `<select>`?  Well, I've got a little war going with `<select>` + `onchange` that [I detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586936/jquery-change-on-select-and-firefox/586969#586969), but basically using it makes your website completely inaccessible to keyboard-only users who are using Internet Explorer 6 or 7.  (Not sure if it is still broken in 8.)

Comment: +1 — I expect this is far and away the simplest method of achieving the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would the url change for different html files? Could you please show how the complete javascript file would look like?

Comment: I'd suggest using `document.getElementById("myiframe")` rather than `document.all.myiframe`. Firefox, at least, doesn't support the latter.

Comment: Thanks again for the page. It works perfectly in IE6, but doesn't work in Firefox 3. Any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know...  I actually tested it in Firefox 3, so it ought to work there.  Maybe there is something else on the page that is causing problems?

Answer (score 5):

If you use JQuery they have a fancy function jquery('#div').load()
http://jquery.com/
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

Works great and also supports GET and POST parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If the drop down is "huge" then I would suggest no longer using a drop down and looking into some of the existing autocompletion boxes out there for your language of choice.

If there are hundreds and hundreds of options a dropdown is no longer an appropriate form element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to accomplish this.  There's a [million different AJAX tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/) out there that can introduce you to the technique.