# Need help with jQuery validation for a select list

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery custom validation method issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824608/jquery-custom-validation-method-issue)

I have a select list #technology. It's default value is "0" due to back end payment processor. I need a validation rule (using jquery.validate.js) that makes it return false if it's value is "0" but return true for any other value. What I am trying isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "SelectTechnology",
            function(value, element) {
                //var selectedCountry = $('#Country').val();
                if ($("#singleTech").val() === '0'){
                    return false;
                } else return true;
            },
            "Please Select a Technology"
        );
        var validator = $("#SinglePmnt").validate({
            rules: {
                    technology: {
                        SelectTechnology: true
                    }
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent("td"));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't clear the error if you hit submit with the default value selected then change it.
thanks

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.  You can edit your old question to bump it back to the top of the Active queue and it will get more views.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `value` to get the passed value

```
if (value == '0')
```

Comment: The extra = is the strict equality operator, which exists in many languages, including javascript. Basically, it checks not only that the values are equal, but also that the variable types are equal. So while 0 == '0', 0 !== '0'. See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't know that.  I suspect the value is the real culprit.  I don't know what field `$("#singleTech").val()` is referencing.

Comment: @RememberME when I change to #("#singleTech").val() == '0' it still has the same issue. If you submit when that value is selected, it displays the error msg as expected. When you change to a different value, it doesn't remove the error msg, although it will submit

Comment: And here's an example of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/BszxG/

Comment: @treface @RememberME #singleTech is a select list, the default value is "0" I don't have an issue getting it to validate, it doesn't remove the validation error msg when you change the select's value.

Comment: The validation is validating #technology, but checking the value of #singleTech.  It will only validate when #technology is changed, not when #singleTech is changed.

Comment: @Dirty, have you taken a look at my answer? It seems to be working fine, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: OK. I see from your previous post that one is the id and one is the name.  You should use `value`, although I'd think your way should work.

Comment: @treeface - saw  your answer on my previous post, doesn't work outside of jsfiddle. not sure what is wrong with my code! rggghhh!

Comment: @RememberME - you mean in place of .val?

Comment: In place of `$("#singleTech").val()`.  The function is being passed `value` which is the value of technology.

Comment: @RememberMe - so how do I fix that?

Comment: live link http://www.kinetick.com/V3/purchase_own.php

Comment: In the .addMethod function replace `if ($("#singleTech").val() === '0')` with `if (value == '0')`

Comment: @RememberMe, thanks Ill give it a try. Much appreciated. Same thing, it will validate but isn't removing the error message onchange.