# jQuery validation not working onchange

Tags: jquery, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery custom validation method issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824608/jquery-custom-validation-method-issue)

I have a select list that is required. It is validating fine, but doesn't remove the error message when you change the select's value. I don't know why, I've used this same code before and not had this issue.

The HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="menu">
    <tr>
        <form action="PHP/Nt6Subscribe.php" method="post" id="SinglePmnt">
            <td width="211">
                <select name="technology" class="select">
                <option value="" selected="selected">&nbsp;Please Select</option>
                <option value="Interactive Brokers">&nbsp;Interactive Brokers</option>
                <option value="MB Trading">&nbsp;MB Trading</option>
                <option value="Patsystems">&nbsp;Patsystems</option>
                <option value="PFG">&nbsp;PFG (Peregrine Financial)</option>
                <option value="TD AMERITRADE">&nbsp;TD AMERITRADE</option>
                <option value="Trading Technologies">&nbsp;Trading Technologies</option>
                <option value="Vision Financial Markets">&nbsp;Vision Financial Markets</option>
                <option value="Hosted">&nbsp;Zen-Fire</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td width="189">Single Payment of $995</td>

            <td width="211">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="34">
                <input type="submit" value="" class="orderNow" />
            </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var validator = $("#SinglePmnt").validate({
            rules: {
                    technology: {
                        required: true
                    }
            },
            messages: {
                    technology: {
                            required: "Please select your broker technology"
                    }
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo(element.parent("td"));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

To sum up it validates when you leave it on "Please Select" which has no value when you hit submit. If you change the value, the error doesn't disappear as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need an id on the select technology select field

Comment: I believe it goes by the name attribute, anyway for grins I added the ID and it still doesn't remove the error message onchange. thx

Comment: hmm, maybe its having a problem because its a select. I never was a big fan of that validator. Could u try validating length to make sure its longer than 0 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing validation in the blur event.

```
$('#singleTech').blur(function(){
  $('#SinglePmnt').validate().element('#singleTech');
});
```

[jQuery change() on <select> and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586936/jquery-change-on-select-and-firefox)

The live link you posted earlier seems to work in IE, but not FireFox.

Comment: What version of the validator do you have?  Your live link doesn't work for me in FireFox, only IE.  But, if I copy your select onto my site (I wanted to test the blur), it does work before any changes.