# mootools select box focus

Tags: select, mootools, blur

I have a select box

```
 <select>
     <option value="0">0 mins</option>
     <option value="1">1 mins</option>
     <option value="2">2 mins</option>
 </select>
```

and I want to fire an event when the visitor either clicks on a value or clicks anywhere else on the page -i.e loss of focus on the select box

I've fiddled about for four hours now with no joy.  I'm now down to this:

```
var c = 0;
$("selectTime").addEvent('click', function() {
    if (c++ % 2 == 1) {
        console.log(c);
       //$(this).blur();
    }
});

$('selectTime').click(function() {
    if ($('select').is(':blur')) {
        c = 1;
    } else {
        c = 0;
    }
});
```

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mootools syntax for adding multiple events to same element is:

```
$('myElementID').addEvents({
    blur: function(){
        alert('blur');
    },
    click: function(){
        alert('click');
    }
});
```

[**Example with you code**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pp8E/)

You could though use just the `change` event, which fires when the element is changed. Like:

```
$('myElement').addEvent('change', function(){
    alert('Select changed');
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pp8E/1/)

Note that part of your code is using jQuery syntax, part is using MooTools syntax.

Comment: Hi thanks for this.  Yes I saw I copied it wrongly, I was playing about with both.  In experimenting I can't get the select box to lose focus without a double click on some other element.  It seems that if you click to the side of a select box then the on blur doesn't seem to be effective.  I have solved th problem now but it involved writing my own "dropdown" which is a div and putting <a> tags around the various lines to simulate a dropdown.  With this set up the on blur event works great - just not with a select

Comment: @user1616338 can you make a fiddle (or adapt mine) with the problem? what browser do you use btw?

Comment: Hi jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/user1616338/vj6BD/ 
I think I've tracked the issue down.  It works fine in IE but not in FF.  If you click on the select box then the drop down appears.  If you then click to the side of the box the drop down dissappears.  Which is what you'd expect.  However in FF you then need to click the page again to get the blur event but in IE the blur event occurs straight away.

Comment: @user1616338, yes, that FF behavior is known. You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586936/jquery-change-on-select-and-firefox

Comment: thanks for the help.I'll mark your solution as the right answer in case anyone is looking for the solution in the future :)