# onchange="javascript: document.my_form.submit()" vs. normal submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select field within a form:

```
<form id="myform">
<select id="value" onchange="javascript: document.myform.submit()">
    <option>....
</select>
</form>
```

After the form is submitted, it is impossible to use the 'back' button without resubmitting the form.  However, if I use a regular 'submit' button, it is possible.

Is there a way you know of to get this behavior while still being able to use the javascript 'submit()'?

Accessibility is not a concern, having javascript enabled is required to use this site and that is the way the client wants it.

Comment: This sounds very browser-specific.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Maybe there is a different approach that will help solve your problem.

Comment: I say this again and again and again, be careful with onchange selects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580281/redirect-automatically-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-select-drop-down-list/580317#580317

Comment: It's for the iPhone, so IE doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok it goes back without re-sending the form, but the onchange="function()" only works the first time...is there any way to re-set that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a function instead.

```
<select id="value" onchange="sendForm()">
```

...script block...

```
function sendForm() {
    document.myform.submit()
}
```

Also, you never need to specify `javascript:` outside of an `HREF` tag.

Comment: Ok it goes back without re-sending the form, but the onchange="sendForm()" only works the first time...is there any way to re-set that?

Comment: I made a test with action="SomeNewPage.htm" and method="post" and iit works fine. What's your form action?

Answer (score 0):

"onchange only works first time?"

Are you re-selecting the same value? onchange only fires when there is a change. If you want to be able to reselect the same option, you need to use onblur.

Also you really should be using

```
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```