# best way to redirect to a selected store

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I set a magento website with several stores, I'm making a list of all thoses stores in a page where the user can pick up the nearest one using a form like this

```
    <form action="<?php echo  ;?>"  method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="select store" />
    </form>

    <form action="<?php echo  ;?>"  method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="select store" />
    </form>
```

In the action attribute I would like to set the url of each store according to his Id...
Is it possible?
Is there a better way to proceed (maybe avoiding GET parameter)?

Edit:
Finally I achieve what I was looking for with this snippet

```
echo '<p><a href="' . Mage::getUrl() . '?___store=' . $store . '">pick up this restaurant</a></p>';
```

It's quite close of what clockworkgeek suggest

```
echo '<p><a href="' .Mage::getUrl('', array('___store'=>$store)) . '">pick up this restaurant</a></p>';
```

but results are differents:

my test:

```
http://test.mysite.com/?___store=3
```

clockworkgeek code:

```
http://test.mysite.com/___store/3/
```

The first link is working fine, the second lead to a 404 one...

Also I try this code which is producing nothing, Any idea why ?

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(5);
$this->_redirect('');
```

The redirection is working fine, but I'm still on the same store, Is it the good way of using setCurrentStore function?

then I finally have a go with this one, but I can find suitable example on the net about it...
how can I using it, and related question how can i Hve the list of all the magento controllers ?

```
 $this->_forward('defaultNoRoute');
```

thx

Comment: It was a kind of "guess the good code" into php brackets, I edit the first post with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of `getUrl()`. For example:

```
echo Mage::getUrl('', array('_store'=>$storeId));
```

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters

Comment: Thx, I need to change it a little bit (check my edit) but I'm not entirely satisfied whit this code as it display get parameter in the URL...

Comment: With this method you only need a single underscore.

Comment: when I do it with a single underscore it redirect me to the base url without changing store...

Comment: What does the result look like compared to your above test?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the submit button using JQuery events and then use `window.location` to redirect to the selected store.

It should be quite similar to the code given in the first answer here:
[Redirect automatically when selecting an item from a select drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580281/redirect-automatically-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-select-drop-down-list)