# How to redirect to another page with Gravity forms drop down value?

Tags: forms, wordpress, gravity

I am trying to create a form in Gravity Forms that consists of a drop down menu. The drop down has names of pages on the site in labels and then corresponding values of page addresses in values. I am trying to send the user to page that they select. How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using the hook here:
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_confirmation

You could grab the value of the dropdown and then redirect based on their selection once they submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript.

```
  // get your select element and listen for a change event on it
  $('#the_drop_down').change(function() {
     // set the window's location property to the value of the option the user has selected
     window.location = $(this).val();
  });
```

via: [Redirect automatically when selecting an item from a select drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580281/redirect-automatically-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-select-drop-down-list)

That post covers issues like *IE compatibility* and using a *jQuery* version.