# Symfony reload table after on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datatable, twig

I have a table of users. and I need to be able to filter them by 'Group'. So when user selects option from drop-down list, I want not the whole page but only users table to reload and display users from that group

This is twig for users table

```
  Filter by group
  <select class="filter-users">
         <option selected></option>
         {% for group in groups %}
                <option>{{ group.name }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
   </select>
   <table id="dataTable">
         <tbody>
             {% for user in users %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.fullName}}</td>
                    </tr>
              {% endfor %}
           </tbody>
       </table>
```

This action to get users by group name

```
 /**
  * @Route("/filter", name="users_filter")
  */
  public function filterAction(Request $request)
  {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $group = $request->request->get('group');

    $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy(['group' => group]);

    return $this->render('AppBundle:User:list.html.twig', [
        'users' => $users
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect automatically when selecting an item from a select drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580281/redirect-automatically-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-select-drop-down-list)

Comment: @TobiasXy i need only certain part of the page to be reloaded. not the redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only the table to be reloaded you could do the following.

First create a template only with the table.

**table.html.twig**

```
       <table id="dataTable">
         <tbody>
             {% for user in users %}
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.fullName}}</td>
                    </tr>
              {% endfor %}
           </tbody>
       </table>
```

**In controller**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

       $group = $request->request->get('group');

       $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy(['group' => group]

       return new Response($this->renderView('table.html.twig', [
           'users' => $users,
       ]));
    }
```

**Then create an ajax call**

```
$('#select-button-div').on('change','#select-button',function() {
    reloadData();
});

function reloadData() {
        let data = {};
        let selected = $('#select-button').find(':selected').text();
        let usersTable = $('#entries');
        usersTable.empty();
        data['selectedVal'] = selected.val();
        let url = Routing.generate('ToYourRoute');
        table.load(url, data);
    }
```