# Call a website when select box changed (HTML, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Helo,

I've got a question.

I've got a selection box in HTML. Now what I want is, that when the selection changed, a website is called with the value.

For example:

```
<select>
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
```

Now, when I choose c, then the URL change.php?option=a is called.

Thank you :-)

Comment: What on earth do you mean by calling a url?

Comment: @VipulSharma i think OP wants to redirect to a new URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect automatically when selecting an item from a select drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580281/redirect-automatically-when-selecting-an-item-from-a-select-drop-down-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need something like this

```
<select>
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
</select>

<script>
var select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {

var myURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + 
window.location.pathname;
document.location = myURL + "?option=" + select.value;

})
</script>
```